# How to construct large const arrays in Rust without manually writing values to construct it

Tags: arrays, rust, constants

**TLDR: What is the best way to construct large `const` arrays without writing all the values manually one by one.**

*Subjective* question below:

I want my program to have an `const` `array` that will hold range of ASCII bytes (`[u8; 94]`), but I don't want to use `Range<u8>`.

And the reason I am not using `Vec` is because I already know the exact range of values I can do it all statically, and I just can't seem to find the way to construct such an array without manually writing each value.

What I did before posting this question was use `const` `Range` because `contains` is *O(1)*.

Anyways regarding original problem, I want this:

```
const VALID_BLOCK_BYTES: [u8; 94] = [32..126; 94];
```

How do I get constant variable array with values from 32 up to 126 without manually writing it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this right now is with a manual loop:

```rust
const VALID_BLOCK_BYTES: [u8; 94] = {
    let mut output = [0; 94];
    
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < 94 {
        output[i as usize] = i + 32;
        i += 1;
    }

    output
};
```

Can't use iterators because traits in const contexts aren't stable.

You can, of course, factor that out into a `const fn` if you need to do that a lot.